# Could not allocate CursorWindow

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-cursor

I'm operating on an *SQLite3* database in my android app. I just read from the pre populated database that has 200k rows and 14 columns. Entries are words. Datatype of all columns is text. Querying for words up to 11 letters (eg. ABANDONMENT) works fine. But for 12 or greater (eg. ABANDONMENTS), the app crashes. Here is the logcat:

```
Could not allocate CursorWindow '//data//data//com.example.myapp//databases//database.sqlite' of size 2097152 due to error -12.
threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40adf9f0)
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2883
android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=861 (# cursors opened by this proc=861)
at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:104)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:162)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:156)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:161)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:201)
at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.query(MainActivity.java:815)
at com.example.myapp.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:356)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

code:

```
query = "select * from words where col_1 = \"" + (myWord)+ "\";";
cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
if (cursor != null)                                          
    cursor.moveToFirst(); // line 815
if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    do {
        for (i = 1; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            temp = cursor.getString(i);
            //other stuff
        }
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    cursor.close();
}
```

So what does the error mean and why is the app crashing?

Comment: The full code would be helpful. Are you closing the cursor after managing it yourself, also why not simply call cursor.moveToNext() instead of !cursor.isAfterLast()

Comment: The full app code is 1000 lines. cursor.isAfterLast is used to check if the cursor has moved through all results and if it has I can stop.

Comment: Are you closing the cursor within the while loop ?

Comment: No. Forgot to paste that line in the code above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was quering in a loop. And closing the cursor inside the loop and not outside solved the problem.

Answer (score 27):

Error -12 means cursor leak.

Try to close it:

```
try {....} finally {  cursor.close();}
```

Comment: I use Kotlin `use` method, it automatically should close everything, so no, it's the problem

Answer (score 7):

Android cursors read all the query results into memory, and have a limit of 1 MB for that data.

This limit was chosen because this amount of data is likely to make your app run sluggishly on a mobile device.

You should, if possible:

- do the computations not in your code but in SQL;
- query only the data that you need (i.e., do not use `SELECT *` but get only the columns you need, and use a `WHERE` filter);
- read the data in smaller portions.

Comment: That's not possible. All rows are unique in the table. So a query gives  only a single result.

Comment: You are certainly getting more than one record. What is the result of the equivalent `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`?