# Android Database - Could not allocate CursorWindow

Tags: android, database

When I often go back and forward in my learning-app (everytime loading the question and answer) i will get this error:

```
01-01 15:27:36.803: E/CursorWindow(3820): Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/*package-name*/databases/quiz.db' of size 2097152 due to error -12.
```

I can't say exactly when I get this error, only that when im often changing the content

Can anybody help me to understand what this error means, please

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not allocate CursorWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495713/could-not-allocate-cursorwindow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495713/could-not-allocate-cursorwindow) you should check if you handle your cursors correctly and if the amount of data you query is too big (check the 2048k limit)

Comment: @What do you mean by "check the 2048k limit" ? How? Thanks

Comment: @Mr.Hyde sorry, I do not remember but a quick search suggest that there is a limit to 1MB for cursor queries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406429/cursor-size-limit-in-android-sqlitedatabase