# Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/com.app/databases/appName.db' of size 123456 due to error -12

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, samsung-mobile

I get those error every time on `SGS4` while using `sqlite`, and on other devices like `SGS3` it works pretty good (with no issues).

Regards

Comment: Please add your source code

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495713/could-not-allocate-cursorwindow