# Android RoomDatabase Cruash "Cursor window allocation of 4194304 bytes failed"

Tags: android, android-room

I got two crush on firebase
1.Caused by android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed.
2.Caused by android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/user/0/com.myname.de/databases/bm_634255623.db' of size 2097152 due to error -12.

i know cursor leak,but i use jetpack room, i can't get cursor

room version:

```
 def room_version = "2.2.5"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

please help me,thanks

why happen this crush?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not allocate CursorWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495713/could-not-allocate-cursorwindow)

Comment: Note that since you haven't posted the calling code it's difficult to be sure, but you're probably creating but not freeing `Cursor`s within a loop somewhere.

Comment: i use jetpack room,i can't get Cursor

Answer (score 0):

This issue could happen because of memory allocation for Cursor. The idea is that the CursorWindows has maximum 2mb so for that query in order to get some consistent data.

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    fun getAll(): List<User>
}
```

You should annotate your DAO methods with @Transaction to get rid of this error.